# TeamCity.war hanging in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, teamcity, osx-server

I have been trying to set up TeamCity 6.5 as a WAR under Tomcat (tried 6 and 7) on Mac OS X Server 10.6. Everything starts fine, but a few seconds of randomly clicking around invariably hangs the entire app and container. I can't even bring up Tomcat's web-app manager or server status pages.

I cannot discern any pattern to when or where the hang occurs, though it does seem to happen more readily the faster I click.

Running `top` shows that the server is spinning at 100% CPU (one core).

Why does TeamCity hang so readily when run as a WAR? The stand-alone version doesn't seem to suffer from the same problem.

Comment: Have you ever solved this issue? I'm experiencing the same on Linux with tomcat6.

Comment: No, I'm afraid I didn't. I am still running it as per my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My two cents on this subject: as I've told you in my comment I was experiencing the same identical issue, tomcat hanging and java with 100% cpu usage. It was happen randomly and the only way to solve it was to kill the process. Until I followed this [page about memory usage](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Installing+and+Configuring+the+TeamCity+Server#InstallingandConfiguringtheTeamCityServer-memory)

When I had the issue I haven't this option in my `JAVA_OPTS`: `-XX:MaxPermSize=200m`, by adding it to other java options given on the environment variable the issue seems to be solved, now TC is running for more than one day with no hangs.

This is my full `JAVA_OPTS` line:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1024m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:MaxPermSize=200m -Dteamcity.data.path=/var/lib/teamcity"
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have the time or inclination to investigate this answer myself, but it seems likely to be the solution, so I'll give you the tick.

Answer (score 1):

- Open JVisualVM (in the bin folder of
  Java 6)
- Under Applications choose your
  running tomcat instance
- Under the Profiler Tab, click CPU
- wait a moment and then click around
  and re-create the problem.

At this point the profiler should show you what is taking your CPU time.

Comment: I couldn't find JVisualVM anywhere on my system. I managed to locate and download VisualVM and configure it to monitor Tomcat via JMX. However, at the point the web interface stops responding, VisualVM stops getting updates from JMX. I am unable to monitor Tomcat directly via the "Local" node, as Tomcat doesn't appear there. I also observed that VisualVM's "Sampler" tab reports "application terminated" shortly after Tomcat hangs.

Comment: if you are using java6, it will be under %java_home%/bin

Comment: A bit more hunting around suggests that VisualVM is the same thing as JVisualVM. Is that the case? If so, then this tool hasn't helped, as I described above. Should I see Tomcat under "Local", or is JMX the correct way to connect to it?

Comment: and yes they are the same thing. jvisualvm is the name of the executable in the bin folder, VisualVM is the name on the application title bar

Comment: How are you running Tomcat? Standalone, from an IDE, service?

Answer (score 1):

Here is some docs on how to detect and report TeamCity hangs:

http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Reporting+Issues#ReportingIssues-HangsandThreadDumps

Answer (score 1):

(I have up-voted the other answers to thank them for their efforts, but neither of them resolved my problem, so I am answering my own question in the negative.)

I have given up and settled for a work-around. I am running TeamCity stand-alone (not as a .war) and added an extra HTTPS port to my firewall. In this configuration, TeamCity works flawlessly.

If someone can provide a resolution that doesn't entail burning another three days of my life, I'll happily move the green tick across to them.

Answer (score 0):

had this problem today, i performed a manual Build History Clean-up and TC performed a clean build (collects all changes again).

to access this via the web browser:

- Administration down left hand menu,
- click Build History Clean-up
- start clean-up now.

additionally i cleaned up log files